# TCP Echo on different adapter

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to write a program for a computer with 2 network adapters (Private and Public) that echoes data received on Private to Public and vice versa. I only need it to listen on two specific ports, and more specifically, it should open a socket server on Private and a socket client on Public.

The computer's IP address on Public is 192.168.1.21 and its IP address on Private is 172.16.13.1, so I thought something like this would work:

```
IPEndPoint privateEndpoint1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.13.1"), port1);
IPEndPoint privateEndpoint2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.13.1"), port2);
IPEndPoint publicEndpoint1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.21"), port1);
IPEndPoint publicEndpoint2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.21"), port2);

TcpListener priList1 = new TcpListener(privateEndpoint1);
TcpListener priList2 = new TcpListener(privateEndpoint2);

TcpClient pubCli1 = new TcpClient(publicEndpoint1); //Error here
TcpClient pubCli2 = new TcpClient(publicEndpoint2);
```

I then get the streams and do the actual echoing.

The problem is that I get an error on the line that I marked:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

It seems from the error that the `IPEndPoint` constructor is not differentiating between the two IP addresses and the two network adapters. I've looked into using normal `Socket`s instead of `TcpClient`s, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: What is the value of `port1` and `port2`?  Also, is there something already listening on `192.168.1.21:port1` ?

Comment: `port1` and `port2` come from the command line arguments. There is another service listening on 192.168.1.21:port1. Basically, the other service is expecting a connection on the wrong network adapter, which is why I'm writing this program.

Comment: It might be much simpler to use something like SSH tunnels to get the traffic going in the right direction.  ;  I can not see any reason your code should be throwing that exception based solely on what you have shown us.

Comment: I actually found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507/controlling-which-network-card-tcp-ip-message-are-sent-on and fixed it by replacing all the `TCPClient` and `TcpListener` with sockets. I'm waiting to see if there is an actual answer with `TCPClient` because, like @Dan-o said, there doesn't seem to be any reason for the exception.